# Referring to range that is the value of a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns, one contains addresses of other cells ($F$2 for example), the other contains colour index numbers (15, for example).

I want to colour the referred-to cell (which is on another sheet).

```vb
Sub Colour_World()
Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In Range("p2:p3907") 'column with cell values

Worksheets("World").Range(Range(Cell).Value).Interior.ColorIndex = Cell.Offset(0, 5).Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think I know how to do it, the problem is that I don't know how to refer to the range that is stored as a value in the first column.

Comment: Please [edit] the post to include the code you have tried and tell us where you are stuck or what error you are getting.

Comment: `Range(Range("A1").Value)` will refer to the range that is stored as text in `A1`

Comment: I have put what I have in my post.

Comment: Change `Range(Cell).Value` to `Cell.Value`.

Comment: Okay, I have put the working macro in the edit; thanks so much!

Comment: Please put the working code in as a answer not as an edit in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because variable `Cell` in `For Each` will return string in `range("p2:p3907")` and when we refer to the range just use only `Range("string refer to cell")`. So, remove one range from your code and it will be as you need. See code below.

```
Sub Colour_World()
Dim Cell As Range

For Each Cell In Range("p2:p3907") 'column with cell values
    Worksheets("World").Range(Cell).Interior.ColorIndex = Cell.Offset(0, 5).Value
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Colour_World()
Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In Range("p2:p10") 'column with cell values

Worksheets("World").Range(Cell.Value).Interior.ColorIndex = Cell.Offset(0, 5).Value


Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub mySub()
    Dim colorCodeRange As Range 'Cell is a keyword so you don't want to try to use it as a variable name.
    Dim outputCell As String
    Dim colorCode As Byte

    Set colorCodeRange = Sheets(1).Range("P2:P10")

    For Each Cell In colorCodeRange.Cells 'either define the range and use it here or don't define the range object and type in a hard-coded range here.
                                          'you were defining the range then not using it, which is pointless.

        outputCell = Cell.Value2 'get the output cell from the color code sheet
        colorCode = Cell.Offset(0, 5).Value 'get the color code
        Sheets("World").Range(outputCell).Interior.ColorIndex = colorCode 'output the color to the "World" sheet

    Next Cell 'be sure to end the loop with "Next Cell" or at least "Next"
End Sub
```

This Sub will get output cells (F2, F3, etc.) from the range P2:P10. These values are in sheet 1. The color codes are in the same row, 5 columns over to the right (column U). The fill colors are output to the "World" sheet in the cell specified in the colorCodeRange variable ("P2:P10").

[image: Sheet 1]

[image: Sheet 2]